# Rewriting only when a file doesn't exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a .htaccess file as it follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I've got this file in my web directory. Is there any way to force this rule to stop rewriting if there's a file?

For example: I've got a css/style.css file but the server returns 404 because the mod_rewrite rule works. If I turn the mod_rewrite off, the file is found.

Comment: I just Googled it and the page that I found had a comment that said, "What did Google say?"  That's what Google said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

  RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ public/assets/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

First block of conditions and the first rule is applied to existing files and folders, and the second rule if an actual rewrite that should happen if there is no file or folder.

Comment: I think `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `!-d` on the existing rule would be simpler.

Comment: In my case it works only prepending with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`

Answer (score 10):

Credit goes to [http://amandine.aupetit.info/135/apache2-mod_rewrite/](http://web.archive.org/web/20151016120949/http://amandine.aupetit.info/135/apache2-mod_rewrite/)

With virtual hosts, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` doesn't match the file path relative to the file system, so you have to use :

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Or its equivalent syntax using `!-f`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you: without %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} the accepted solution does not work most of the times.