# Apache - .htaccess Rewrite Rules, unable to see the existing files content

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am developing an IFSC code finder script.

I have some files already named `about.php`, `privacy-policy.php`, `contact-us.php`, and some other files and folders.

My `.htaccess` file content is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about.html$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy.html$ privacy-policy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us.html$ contact-us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search.html$ search.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3&branch=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?bank=$1&state=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?bank=$1 [QSA]
```

Now, I want that the files which are already existing like `about.html` or `about.php` and so on should be shown instead of passing the query to custom rewrite condition. For example when I try to visit http://example.com/ifsc/about.html then the about.html file should be shown instead of passing it as http://example.com/ifsc/?branch=index.html

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381421/1173182), you should probably check beforehand if the requested file (not folder) exists, then skip all rewriterules if it does.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
```

(I'm not a guru in mod_rewrite, please double-check)

Comment: Thanks, it worked like charm. And I am sorry for adding a similar question as I had searched but didn't get the answer may be due to searching the wrong query. Thanks