# How to rewrite URL this way in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

– My main logic page is at “site.com/main-page/”.
– What I need is: A visitor can request whatever URL (not an existing physical file or folder) and while they see their requested URL in their browser address bar, the content is served from our main processing page at “site.com/main-page/”
– Adding this line in .htaccess did not work and visitors get a 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^.$ /main-page/ [L] #custom line added
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] #default code by WP. Custom code added above this line.
```

What are the alternatives available in WordPress to achieve what I need?

Thank you.

Comment: `^.$` allows for exactly _one_ arbitrary character.

Comment: [Rewriting only when a file doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19381332/1427878)

Comment: Just to clarify, you can't do this in `.htaccess` as WordPress simply does not see the rewritten URL, so naturally generates a 404 based on the URL the user requested. You need to do this using WordPress itself.