# htaccess RewriteRule only work on exist path, any way to work on the non exist one too?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess file , on Apache server

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login.php https://google.com
```

, the login.php is at the root folder, the above script work, but the following does not redirect

```
RewriteRule /login https://google.com
RewriteRule /test https://google.com
```

How to apply the rules when the file / path is not exist? Thank you

for more detail: I found that

`RewriteRule ^product_list.php google.com [L] works`

but

`RewriteRule ^product_list google.com [L]` not works

it seems not matching the rule, are there any settings to allow without .php first? Thank you

Comment: Can you describe scenario more? All paths should go to Google, all those that don't exist, or just the 3 defined here? As one rule this would be `RewriteRule ^login(\.php)?|test) https://google.com`. For doesn't exist see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381332/rewriting-only-when-a-file-doesnt-exist

Comment: for more detail: I found that

RewriteRule ^product_list.php https://google.com [L] works

but 

RewriteRule ^product_list https://google.com [L] not works

it seems not matching the rule

seems I need change the settings to remove .php first?

Comment: Or just `FallbackResource https://google.com`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^product_list.php google.com [L] works` - How does that "work"? (That's not a redirect, it's an internal rewrite to a relative URL-path - which I would expect would result in a 404.) For context, `RewriteRule ^product_list.php google.com [L]` is very different to `RewriteRule ^product_list.php https://google.com [L]`

Comment: `RewriteRule /login https://google.com` - What URL are you requesting? That won't match if you are requesting a URL of the form `example.com/login`. The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does not include a slash prefix. What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: On a separate note, if you want to make `.php` optional then use: `^product_list(?:\.php)?/?$`